# Make a javascript menu open when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a css menu that I found on the web and would like to add some javascript to it to enable a menu to be automatically opened when the page loads. I'm rubbish with javascript, so could do with some help. Below is the JS code. I have four menu's in the HTML with one sub menu; at the moment, which contain 'a' links. I would like the first menu to open on page load, which will reveal it's submenu.

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function (index, e) {
            var count = $(e).find('li').length;
            var content = '<span class="cnt">' + count + '</span>';
            $(e).closest('li').children('a').append(content);
        });
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');
        $('#cssmenu ul ul li:even').addClass('even');
        $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
            $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
                checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            }
            if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            }
            if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the double `document.ready`? `$('#cssmenu > ul:first > li > a').click();`?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle on that?

Comment: `$('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');` two times?

Comment: Sorry, I'm also new to StackOverflow too :-S: There is meant to be only one $('#cssmenu ul ul li:odd').addClass('odd');

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinbil/myJaM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#cssmenu ul li:eq(0)").addClass('active');
 $("#cssmenu ul li:eq(0) ul").css('display','block');
```

add this piece of code and try
demo 
    http://jsfiddle.net/myJaM/3/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much, worked a treat. One question on from that, can I change which menu is open on page load ? i.e. 'Other Stuff' menu rather than 'Geeky Stuff' menu?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/myJaM/4/ try this fiddle ,please give me up vote if my answer is useful

Comment: Again, brilliant thanks very much Karthhick :) Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `active` class to your first `<li class="has-sub">` and add `display: block;` to the `<ul>` inside. No JQuery needed.

```
<li class='has-sub active'><a href='#'><span>Geeky Sites</span></a>
   <ul style="display: block;">
      <li class='last'><a href='http://tools.email-checker.com/' target='_blank'><span>SMTP Checker</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Great thanks AfromanJ. The js code Karthick suggested also works, but I'll go with your suggestion so I can edit in HTML and use the js file for other menus on my site :) Thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in jQuery as opposed to CSS (for transferability, perhaps) you have two choices:

- either extract the onclick event as a separate function and run that with the top element like so http://jsfiddle.net/myJaM/1/ (`open($("#cssmenu li *")[0]);`)
- or trigger the click event after attaching it http://jsfiddle.net/myJaM/2/ (`$($("#cssmenu li *")[0]).click();`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be open on start, why not just add the `active` class to the `li`, and `display: block` to the child `ul`?

Or are you looking for the animation to run at start? If so do this at the end of your document.load function:

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li:first > a').trigger('click');
```

On a side note your styling classes (last, odd and even) are unncessary. Try using `:nth-last-child`, `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`.